# Where does log4j Socket Appender write to

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am using log4j2 to write to syslog. I am using the socket appender. I am wondering which facility does it write to? When I use Syslog appender, I can specifiy the facility but there is no option in socket appender. My log4j2.xml file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+SS:SS]} [%-5p] %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Socket name="SYSLOG" host="localhost" port="514" protocol="UDP">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="&lt;1&gt;%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss} ${hostName} appName: {
                &quot;host&quot;:&quot;${hostName}&quot;,
                &quot;thread&quot;:&quot;%t&quot;,
                &quot;level&quot;:&quot;%p&quot;,
                &quot;logger&quot;:&quot;%c{1}&quot;,
                &quot;line&quot;:%L,
                &quot;message&quot;:&quot;%enc{%m}&quot;,
                &quot;exception&quot;:&quot;%exception&quot;
                }%n"
            />
        </Socket>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="SYSLOG"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I need to write to local0 facility. I am using syslog-ng to write to a file then. My syslog-ng.conf file is:

```
#Filters
filter f_my_app { facility(local0)};
#Destinations
destination d_my_app { file("/data/logs/scheduler/scheduler.log" template("[$ISODATE][$LEVEL] $MSG\r\n") create-dirs(yes)); };
#Log Paths
log { source(s_src); filter(f_my_app); destination(d_my_app); flags(final); };
```

In the current configurations, it does not write to facility0.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to write to the syslog then you should use the [`Syslog` appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender). The (plain) socket appender doesn't support all the features of the `Syslog` appender.

Answer (score 0):

The SocketAppender with the [SyslogLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#SyslogLayout) or [RFC5424Layout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#RFC5424Layout) is equivalent to the [SyslogAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender). If you will notice it is the Layout's that have the Facility, not the SocketAppender. Saying "Where does it write to?" with respect to the facility is incorrect. The Facility is just a category messages being logged fit into. Local0 through Local7 are not used by the system and so are recommended for applications to use.

It is incorrect to use the PatternLayout when writing to syslog. There is at least one enhancement request to allow a pattern to be used to format just the message portion of the log event but that has not yet been implemented.

Syslog-ng supports both the BSD (RFC 3164) and Structured (RFC 5424) log events. You will need to determine which format you want to use. Despite RFC 5424 being newer, BSD style log events are still predeominant.

Comment: When I use BSD format, the first word in my log message is truncated. I don't know why it does that. That is why I want to use Socket Appender with the custom layout

Comment: In my log42.xml file that I have shared above, where should I mention facility so that it would write to LOCAL0?